# How to disable/enable text box depends on Enum?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, enums

I am working in MVC C#. I have a table with Enum  values. I got 2 conditions in Enum as On and Off. I want my text box to be Enabled during On and Disabled during Off. How to do this ? kindly help.
My text box as follows:

```
<div ><p class="form_text1">Start</p> <input type="text" id="EditStart" name="EditStart" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

Comment: `$("#EditStart").prop("disabled", !(Enum == "On"))`

Comment: How are you fetching/renderng your Enum value in your page ?

Comment: @guradio I need add this in View Script Page right? I tried its not working.

Comment: @BasantaMatia actually I use a pop up window to edit.. if my enum got off means I need to disable this start text box

Comment: where is your enum value ? How you are keeping it in your view ?

Comment: Our Team Created those things. I am actually new to this. When I check I found My enum Declared with datatype 'trantype' in table and enum values declared in separate model page

Comment: @guradio Thankyou so much I used ur one with little modifications on script, its working. I tried to mark ur one as answer, but I can't find tick mark on this link

Comment: @Ben77 as long as it works its ok.. glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bit more of a generic approach, you can do this through C# instead of JavaScript. However, I am unsure how you are getting this **enum** so my answer might not work. Hope this helps.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumTextBox(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            YourEnum enum)
{
    object attributes = null;
    if(enum == YourEnum.Off)
    {
        attributes = new
                     {
                         disabled = "disabled"
                     };
    }

    return htmlHelper.TextBox("YourTextBoxName", null, attributes);
}
```

*Note:* I did not test this, just wrote it out from head.

Comment: Sir I just need to copy paste ur things in controller ah? I am new to MVC. YourEnum( I need to put my enum name)..anything else I need to change?

Comment: No. This would go in a separate file (and directory) in your MVC project. You would then import the namespace and use it in your view with the model that contains the `enum`. These are called `HtmlHelper`s if you want to research them.

Comment: I am bit Confused...

Comment: You mentioned you are new to MVC, so with that I would suggest you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) to familiarize yourself with MVC. Helping you understand views, models, etc is outside the scope of this question. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I understand the model view controllers.. but to add this html helpers outside I am bit confused where to add .. under which folder?

Comment: Generic folder, like `Helpers` or `Utilities` (for example). This is what I meant [basic html helper example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed description and help. But I fix this using script method, as by first answer. I gave 1 up vote for ur answer